Attempt to insert record on page
I have this error when trying to save the page, i have added a new Tab to pages and when i try to save this error is showing:
1: Attempt to insert record on page 'Page name' (371) where this table, tx_myext_domain_model_name, is not allowed

I already tried to add the model table to allowed pages adding this line to ext_localconf.php:
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_myext_domain_model_name');

I also check if there is anything allowed or denied like this in ts_config mod.web_list.allowedNewTables / deniedNewTables
Project TYPO3 version 11
Do you have another idea to try ?
Thanks

The method doc block looks like
/**
 * Add tablename to default list of allowed tables on pages (in $PAGES_TYPES)
 * Will add the $table to the list of tables allowed by default on pages as setup by $PAGES_TYPES['default']['allowedTables']
 * FOR USE IN ext_tables.php FILES
 *
 * @param string $table Table name
 */
public static function allowTableOnStandardPages($table) {}

Move it to your extension ext_tables.php file instead of the ext_localconf.php file.
Sadly, you did not provide the place where you want to add the record. If it is a normal (standard page) you need to call the method above. Adding it to sysfolders should work out of the box.
But if you want to add it to the root node, you need to set the TCA ctrl option rootLevel [1] for your table, either in Configuration/TCA/tx_myext_domain_model_entity.php or Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_myext_domain_model_entity.php.
// Configuration/TCA/tx_myext_domain_model_entity.php
return [
  'ctrl' => [
    // ...

    //  0 (false): Default. Can only exist in the page tree
    //  1 (true) : Can only exist in the root
    // -1        : Can exist in both page tree and root 
    'rootLevel' => -1,
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
];

or
// Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_myext_domain_model_entity.php
//  0 (false): Default. Can only exist in the page tree
//  1 (true) : Can only exist in the root
// -1        : Can exist in both page tree and root 
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_entity']['ctrl']['rootLevel'] = 0;

[1] https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/RootLevel.html#rootlevel

Yes the new tab is adding content on regular page and root page, i have tried both configuration but still not running
